# Removing duplicate nodes from xsl output

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, grouping, distinct

Given the following Xml:

```
<record>
    <category>Sport/Racket Sports/Tennis</category>
    <category>Sport/Racket Sports/Badminton</category>
</record>
```

I'm trying to break up the categories so that the following Xml is produced:

```
<add>
   <doc>
      <field name="category_0">Sport</field>
      <field name="category_1">Sport/Racket Sports</field>
      <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Tennis</field>
      <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Badminton</field>
   </doc>
</add>
```

I've managed to produce something which is nearly there.. I now need a way of removing the duplicates? Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="record">
        <add>
            <doc>
                <xsl:for-each select="category[. != '']">
                    <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="number(0)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </doc>
        </add>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split-cats">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($text, '/')">
                    <field>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, substring-before($text, '/'))"/>
                    </field>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, concat(substring-before($text, '/'), '/'))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '/')"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <field>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $text)"/>
                    </field>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>        
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template produces:

```
<add>
   <doc>
      <field name="category_0">Sport</field>
      <field name="category_1">Sport/Racket Sports</field>
      <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Tennis</field>
      <field name="category_0">Sport</field>
      <field name="category_1">Sport/Racket Sports</field>
      <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Badminton</field>
   </doc>
</add>
```

Which as you can see has `Sport` and `Sport/Racket Sports` in there twice :(

FYI: I need to be able to do this using XSLT 1.0

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Please, in a separate question explain what are the requirements/rules for producing the output (in particular, it isn't clear how the category names should be formed). I think a simpler solution can be produced and the problem of having duplicates might be avoided altogether.

Comment: Ah yes.. sorry the number represents the "level" of the category where "0" is the root level.. in this case "Sport" and "1" is the first level of subcategory, 2 is the 2nd level of subcategory etc.   It's a notation that's used in order to send a document to Solr.  Look at the 3rd option in this email http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/8a14673728e3a722/implementing_hierarchical_facet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straight-forward approach that simply inserts a second transformation step using Muenchian grouping on the result your code creates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="cats/field" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:variable name="cats">
          <cats>
                <xsl:for-each select="category[. != '']">
                    <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
          </cats>
        </xsl:variable>
        <add>
            <doc>
              <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($cats)/cats/field[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]"/>
            </doc>
        </add>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split-cats">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($text, '/')">
                    <field>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, substring-before($text, '/'))"/>
                    </field>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, concat(substring-before($text, '/'), '/'))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '/')"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <field>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $text)"/>
                    </field>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>        
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That makes use of `exsl:node-set` however, if you target XSLT 1.0 in the browsers then for IE/MSXML you need to fix it with the script shown in http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html.

Comment: Thanks.. I wasn't sure what the node-set was.. just looked it up and seems you can do this in .NET using the xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt namespace too :)

Comment: If you use .NET and XslCompiledTransform then you can use my stylesheet as posted (as XslCompiledTransform supports the node-set function in both the EXSLT namespace and the Microsoft one). If you use .NET and XslTransform then you are right, you need to change the namespace URI to the one you posted.

Comment: @CraftyFella: To use `XslCompiledTransform` is better because besides other things it use pseudo standard EXSLT namespace URI. Also, check my answer for a without extension solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without making use of extension function (but which will not necessarily be as efficient asusing Muenchian grouping) is to add a check to compare previous category records to see if they begin with the string you are about to about

```
<xsl:if test="not(/record/category
              [. != '']
              [position() &lt; $pos]
              [substring(., 1, string-length($field-text)) = $field-text])">
```

In this bit of code **$pos** is a parameter containing the position of the current **category** element you are currently matching, and **$field-text** is a variable containing the text you are about to output.

Here is the complete XSLT stylesheet, which should also give you the output you desire

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="record">
      <add>
         <doc>
            <xsl:for-each select="category[. != '']">
               <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
                  <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="level" select="number(0)"/>
                  <!-- Position of the current category -->
                  <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </doc>
      </add>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="split-cats">
      <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
      <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
      <xsl:param name="pos"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($text, '/')">
            <xsl:variable name="field-text" select="concat($prefix, substring-before($text, '/'))"/>
            <!-- Test no previous category begins with the text we are about to output -->
            <xsl:if test="not(/record/category
                             [. != '']
                             [position() &lt; $pos]
                             [substring(., 1, string-length($field-text)) = $field-text])">
               <field>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">
                     <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$field-text"/>
               </field>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="split-cats">
               <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, concat(substring-before($text, '/'), '/'))"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '/')"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="field-text" select="concat($prefix, $text)"/>
            <!-- Test no previous category begins with the text we are about to output -->
            <xsl:if test="not(/record/category
                             [. != '']
                             [position() &lt; $pos]
                             [substring(., 1, string-length($field-text)) = $field-text])">
               <field>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">
                     <xsl:text>category_</xsl:text>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$field-text"/>
               </field>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without extension functions, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="record">
        <add>
            <doc>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="category[1]"/>
            </doc>
        </add>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="category" name="category">
        <xsl:param name="pOutput"/>
        <xsl:param name="pPrefix"/>
        <xsl:param name="pLevel" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSequence" select="concat(.,'/')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pSequence">
                <xsl:variable name="vItem"
                              select="concat($pPrefix,
                                             substring-before($pSequence,
                                                              '/'))"/>
                <xsl:variable name="vOutput"
                              select="concat('|',$vItem,'|')"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(contains($pOutput,$vOutput))">
                    <field name="category_{$pLevel}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vItem"/>
                    </field>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:call-template name="category">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pOutput"
                                    select="concat($pOutput,$vOutput)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pPrefix" 
                                    select="concat($vItem,'/')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pLevel" select="$pLevel + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                                    select="substring-after($pSequence,'/')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::category[1]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pOutput" select="$pOutput"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="category_0">Sport</field>
        <field name="category_1">Sport/Racket Sports</field>
        <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Tennis</field>
        <field name="category_2">Sport/Racket Sports/Badminton</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```